# how to install <vlc/vlc.h>

Tags: compiling, libraries, media-library

```
In file included from channel.cpp:20:0:
header.h:4:21: fatal error: vlc/vlc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <vlc/vlc.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.obj/channel.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to compile?

Answer (score 3):

In all supported versions of Ubuntu vlc.h is provided by *libvlc-dev*. This package contains headers and a static library required to build standalone applications that use VLC features. To install libvlc-dev open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev
```

When libvlc-dev is installed, the path to vlc/vlc.h is `/usr/include/vlc/vlc.h`

Answer (score 1):

@karel answer is the correct one. But in the spirit of "*teach them to fish*": if you need to find which package provides a certain file, install `apt-file`

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

(repeat the update from time to time) and then, in your case:

```
[romano:~] % apt-file search vlc/vlc.h    
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/vlc.h
```